# moderators limited, downvoting abuse on new users

Tags: discussion, support

For any reason moderator are declining flags from me i have send it 2 time.
about donwvoting my question, and donwvoting user not give any type o feedback/comment/edit.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/204507?showDeclined=true

[image]

**I have proof that they are doing a bad job:**

Clearly in this code review page it is indicated how and when to use the Flags, it does not explicitly say that it is only to moderator verify content related issues.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

[image]

**NEXT donwvoting say:**

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down

[image]

***Summarizing:***

I am sure that the use of negative votes are extreme and harmful to / towards new users. to vote negatively to a post from a new person and not to leave any type of Comment / Warning or communication as indicated by the pages that I visit; border on abuse or misuse of negative voting tools; and the fact that the moderators decline the flags without doing anything is even worse.

**I believe that negative votes should not be allowed to people who have not actively participated in a post or left a comment, and less in the posts of people who have less than 100 points.**

**Update:**

Why Downvote???
my respects to [mickmackusa](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/141885/mickmackusa) the only person who at the moment, despite not being a moderator, is aware of my point of view, how permissive and harmful negative votes are.

[image]

Comment: You're talking about [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/244578/52915), correct? That's not your first question and the earlier one was better received, so you *have* participated before, correct?

Comment: *"I have proof that they are doing a bad job"*. No, you don't. A negative score is the sum of the community's reaction on your post. It's not the moderators job to stop individual downvotes, it's their "job" to stop serial downvotes (e.g. if a user were to downvote all your posts systematically). There is usually a reason why your question isn't well-received ([see my comment on your question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244578#comment480207_244578)), and your free to [ask on meta](/questions/ask) why and how to improve your post. Accusations however aren't helpful.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Stack Exchange and all other associated sites are a community where non-robots reside with predefined behavior patterns.

As a society; Negative nuances should not exist since this society was founded in search of Improving and Sharing Knowledge.

Instead of prescribing negative nuances; Tools that objectively stand out because someone disagrees and should not leave everything to a system of speculation (negative votes) should be used.

If I agree that the good posts should be in the post accumulating positive votes, and every society would be.

I am not the one to say that the "moderators are useless" but I can say that they are the hands and feet of this community, and they are the channel to achieve radical changes, if they are also interested, of course.

Comment: See this post on Meta Stack Exchange https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: best answer in the post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158/801721

Comment: You may have noticed that members of the community have made an effort to correct the issues in the question, it is now up to the  members of the community to reopen the question.

Comment: @pacmaninbw thank you; i love your help.

Comment: @pacmaninbw OP decided to remove the question.

Comment: " I am not the one to say that the "moderators are useless" " That was exactly the title of this question on first revision.

Comment: @Mast it is right; it was decided to delete the question and present it again under the concepts and words of the moderators and users, who voiced the previous one; to the point where it was closed. cant fin this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244622/variables-exporter

Comment: @WalterNuñez it already had 3 votes to reopen the original question.

Comment: i dont know i cant view it???

Answer (score 10):

You're using flags the wrong way. Two downvotes aren't 'extreme'; users aren't require to disclose why they downvote (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325416/295232) for reasons why) and ♦ moderators **can't do anything about it** – they're able to see *patterns* of one user repeatedly downvoting another one, they [can't see individual votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12985/295232).

Comment: Why disagreed with the post, if not check it? it really seems kind of mean!

Comment: you agree that: if I don't like that answer you just gave me; I put a negative vote and you do not know why, just by knowing that someone did not like this.

Comment: That happens, yes. I'm happy that most of the time the reverse happens: users upvote my answer and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 10):

I'm the moderator that declined these flags.
To put it somewhat bluntly: There's nothing that I as a moderator can do about downvotes, unless there's clear evidence of vote abuse.

All I can see is that a question that had ... formulation difficulties that are hard to put into words and that skirts the line of being on topic was downvoted twice.
That's not something a moderator is really needed for or able to resolve in the first place.

Comment: you agree that: if I don't like that answer you just gave me; I put a negative vote and you do not know why, just by knowing that someone did not like this...??

Comment: it is true, I must blindly believe in what you say because this is not a democracy; you are the all powerful moderator who says and decides what you can and cannot do based on the privileges you have; I think this would not be management if it is a paid service, in conclusion: either the moderators lack more options or the negative feedback tool says a lot and at the same time says nothing ...

Comment: @WalterNuñez Moderators are users and not employees of the company, they are not paid for what they do. They generally run for the office of Moderator during an election. Everything you are saying about moderators is abusive and could be flagged as such. They have somewhat greater privileges than regular users but they really can't see that much more than us.

Comment: I wrote it with all the intention of touching that subject; I have not used any language that is abusive; I am describing a situation, I know they are not paid. I know they don't have an office. It is the effort they make to be moderators is great, but also because you want a user to put yourself in your place, you must put yourself in the place of a new user.

Answer (score 6):

Walter, I understand being downvoted can feel harsh and hurt. And I agree that downvoting without commenting isn't constructive. But saying "moderators useless" is verbal abuse, and fighting what you see as abuse with abuse is not going to help your cause.

> I have proof that they are doing a bad job
>
> 7. In need of moderator intervention.

This just simply isn't the case. Users can vote however they please. And the users likely are using them in the way the downvote privilege page tells them to.

> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

The users could have a super high standard and think you've put no effort into your post. Who knows, since they didn't interact with the post otherwise. Currently there's even [a push on Stack Overflow to encourage downvoting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398537), where some want to focus on telling users that downvotes aren't akin to saying "you're an evil bad person". It's a tool to signal to others that there are problems with the post.

> I believe that negative votes should not be allowed to people who have not actively participated in a post or left a comment

This is something that Stack Exchange Inc. would have to implement. Our moderators cannot enforce that.

Comment: ** This is something that Stack Exchange Inc. would have to implement. Our moderators cannot enforce that. ** It is a suggestion .... but what they can do is remove negative votes and draw attention to their misuse, as given, a negative vote without any comment is unconstructive. .. little worse than the moderators see the activity of the post and do nothing .... I would like to know what is wrong with the Initial post, but how can I determine.

Comment: @WalterNuñez "but what they can do is remove negative votes" you're making assumptions on the powers that moderators have. "I would like to know what is wrong with the Initial post" a moderator can't extract that information from some random person on the internet any more than you can. They can't make the user comment.

Comment: seriously, this seems like a mockery: you say that a moderator has no way of knowing if a post has something that he dislikes, but another common user can determine that something in the post displeases him, vote negatively because it came out of him nothingness, is what you tell me is correct and habitual. I think that the tool does not have the expected utility and the moderators are not objective. It is as if a person placed a stone on someone else's car because they do not like what they saw; without saying anything, then a policeman (moderator) says that it is correct behavior

Comment: @WalterNuñez watch which analogies you're trying to pull here. Moderators ***can not do*** the things you expect them to be able to do. That's not the fault of the moderators.

Comment: you agree that: if I don't like that answer you just gave me; I put a negative vote and you do not know why, just by knowing that someone did not like this

Comment: @Vogel612 I am not blaming the moderators for not doing what I expect; They are misinterpreted the post: I do not know the scope of a moderator but I know that within their privileges and tools there are multiple things that they can do; but if you look they just decline the flags ... and use any kind of vague or generic response that doesn't contribute at all.

Comment: @WalterNuñez You're talking like you think I've never been downvoted before. I have. I have been downvoted on Code Review at least 135 times. Some of my posts have been deleted so it's probably more around 150. Your 2 downvotes are but a drop in the ocean to me, and you want to make bigger waves then I ever have...